# omniauth-facebook user model data types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I'm following the railscasts facebook authentication episode http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication and he creates the user model via

```
rails g model user provider uid name oauth_token oauth_expires_at:datetime
```

My problem is that I already have a user model (which I called master) so I tried a migration:

```
class AddomniauthfacebookattributesToMasters < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :masters, :provider
    add_column :masters, :uid
    add_column :masters, :name
    add_column :masters, :oauth_token
    add_column :masters, :oauth_expires_at, :datetime 
  end
end
```

but I realized that he didn't put any data types for the first 4 columns.

1st question: What should the data types be? string, integer, string, string?
2nd question: Since I already had a user model (which I called master) can I incorporate the omniauth-facebook authorization into the Master model or, since I have changed to default name (user to master) do I still have to make a brand new user model?

Any help is appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rails g model` command (which is an abbreviated version of `rails generate model`) sets the data types as strings by default. So all those columns should be strings.

Even though the `uid` may consist in just numbers, most of the time it will be too large to fit in an integer column. Also, sometimes, depending on the provider, it may include letters and other characters, so that field should definitely be of type string.

Finally, you can still use omniauth-facebook with your `Master` model. Just make sure you remember to change the usual `User` references to `Master`.